# JavaFX setOnScrollStarted and setOnScrollFinished not working

Tags: java, javafx, scroll

I want to implement `onScrollStarted` and `onScrollFinished` in **javaFX** but they are not working,although `setOnScroll` is working.Sample Code:

```
    //One Way
    node.setOnScrollStarted(s -> {
        System.out.println("ScrollFinished..");
        node.setCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE);
    });

    node.setOnScrollFinished(s -> {
        System.out.println("ScrollStarted...");
        node.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    });

    //Other Way
    node.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL_STARTED, (x) -> {
        System.out.println("ScrollStarted...");
        node.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    });

    node.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL_FINISHED, (x) -> {
        System.out.println("ScrollFinished..");
        node.setCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE);
    });
```

None of the above are working.
Where node is a `textField`.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`ScrollEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html) :

> When the scrolling is produced by a touch gesture (such as dragging a finger over a touch screen), it is surrounded by the SCROLL_STARTED and SCROLL_FINISHED events.  ...  **When the scrolling is caused by a mouse wheel rotation, only a one-time SCROLL event is delivered, without the started/finished surroundings**

If you are using a mouse wheel you will not get these events.

Comment: Nice and bad news.

Comment: Is there an equivalent option for mouse scroll so that the event is fired immediately instead of when the scroll bar reaches the top or bottom?